# What is the difference between start and enable in the Oracle RAC srvctl?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-rac

In the Oracle 12c documentation it was not clear what is the difference between the *srvctl start* and *srvctl enable* commands for services associated with a database.
In the view **dba_service** a database that has a service already started, has the column *ENABLED* with *NO*, what I noticed is that when a RAC service has already started and you try to enable it, it informs you that it is already enabled.

```
srvctl enable service -d mydb -s myservice
PRCC-1010: myservice was already enabled
PRCR-1002: Resource ora.mydb.myservice.svc is already enabled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable means the service can be used and it will autostart when the cluster is restarted.
Also, you can have a service enabled, but with the current status stoped.
If you change the service to disable, you can't start the service.

Comment: Just to expand and clarify - "Enable means the service _can_ be used and it will autostart _when_ the cluster is restarted."_   And 'start' means "start it _now_".  So "enable" is a passive configuration, and "start", is an active command.